# How to avoid wildcard capture error and how to fix it?

Tags: java, generics

The idea of design is GenericFileService maintains a list of candidate instances of FileService implementations. Each instance can only handle a specific fileType. GenericFileServiceImpl implements GenericFileService and provide a generic method saveFileInfo to accept any supported fileType. I think this should work at runtime, but I got wildcard capture compile error. Could you explain why? How to fix it?

```
    interface FileInfo {
        String getFileType();
    }

    static class MsdsFileInfo implements FileInfo {
        private String fileType;

        @Override
        public String getFileType() {
            return fileType;
        }

        /*
        ... Other msds file specific properties
        * */
    }

    static class NdgcFileInfo implements FileInfo {
        private String fileType;

        @Override
        public String getFileType() {
            return fileType;
        }

        /*
        ... Other ndgc file specific properties
        * */
    }

    interface FileService<T extends FileInfo> {
        void saveFileInfo(T fileInfo);

        boolean support(String fileType);
    }

    static class MsdsFileService implements FileService<MsdsFileInfo> {

        @Override
        public void saveFileInfo(MsdsFileInfo fileInfo) {
            // implementation for MsdsFileInfo
        }

        @Override
        public boolean support(String fileType) {
            return StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(fileType, "MSDS");
        }
    }

    static class NdgcFileService implements FileService<NdgcFileInfo> {

        @Override
        public void saveFileInfo(NdgcFileInfo fileInfo) {
            // implementation for NdgcFileInfo
        }

        @Override
        public boolean support(String fileType) {
            return StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(fileType, "NDGC");
        }
    }


    interface GenericFileService {
        <T extends FileInfo> void saveFileInfo(String fileType, T fileInfo);
    }

    static class GenericFileServiceImpl implements GenericFileService {
        private final List<FileService<? extends FileInfo>> candidateFileServices = new ArrayList<>();

        public GenericFileServiceImpl() {
            candidateFileServices.add(new MsdsFileService());
            candidateFileServices.add(new NdgcFileService());
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends FileInfo> void saveFileInfo(String fileType, T fileInfo) {
            FileService<? extends FileInfo> fileService = candidateFileServices.stream()
                    .filter(service -> service.support(fileType))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported fileType.");
                    });

            // Got wildcard capture error here
            fileService.saveFileInfo(fileInfo);
        }
    }
```

Below is the error message:

```
error: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to CAP#1
            fileService.saveFileInfo(fileInfo);
                                     ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends FileInfo declared in method <T>saveFileInfo(String,T)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you, where is the problem with this code.

Consider this piece of code you provided：

```
private final List<FileService<? extends FileInfo>> candidateFileServices = new ArrayList<>();

public GenericFileServiceImpl() {
    candidateFileServices.add(new MsdsFileService());
    candidateFileServices.add(new NdgcFileService());
}
```

You defined the variable `candidateFileServices`, type is `List<FileService<? extends FileInfo>>`

So, you can add `new MsdsFileService()` and `new NdgcFileService()` in this List

Then you use

```
FileService<? extends FileInfo> fileService = candidateFileServices.stream()...
```

get a `fileService`, type is `FileService<? extends FileInfo>`.

So, which Object can be hold by the `fileService`? `MsdsFileService`、`NdgcFileService` and any class which extends `FileService`

Then the code `fileService.saveFileInfo(fileInfo);`

Looking back at its method signature：

```
interface FileService<T extends FileInfo> {
    void saveFileInfo(T fileInfo);

    boolean support(String fileType);
}
```

Its argument is FileInfo or a subtype of FileInfo.

When you use that fileService to call the method `saveFileInfo`, In fact, at the compilation stage, the compiler cannot determine the type of its parameters at all, so it can only be represented by **T**, but T is FileInfo or a subtype of FileInfo.

Therefore, the java compiler will consider it unsafe

Because fileService may be `MsdsFileService`、`NdgcFileService` and any class which extends `FileService`,  the parameter of the method `saveFileInfo` may be `FileInfo` or a **any subtype of** `FileInfo`

But you can't use `MsdsFileService` to call method `saveFileInfo(NdgcFileInfo)`.

In addition, this code, it seems, is deliberately using generics, but in fact it does not need it at all：

```
interface FileInfo { }

class File1Info implements FileInfo { }
class File2Info implements FileInfo { }

interface FileService {
    void saveFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo);
}

class File1Service implements FileService {
    @Override
    public void saveFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo) {

    }
}

class File2Service implements FileService {
    @Override
    public void saveFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo) { }
}

interface GenericFileService {
    void saveFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo);
}

class GenericFileServiceImpl implements GenericFileService {
    private final List<FileService> candidateFileServices = new ArrayList<>();

    public GenericFileServiceImpl() {
        candidateFileServices.add(new File1Service());
        candidateFileServices.add(new File2Service());
    }
    @Override
    public void saveFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo) {
        candidateFileServices.forEach(fileService -> fileService.saveFileInfo(fileInfo));
    }
}
```

If you must use generics, you need to modify it to ensure type safety：

```
interface GenericFileService {
    <T extends FileInfo, R extends FileService<T>> void saveFileInfo(T fileInfo, R fileService);

    FileService<? extends FileInfo> getFileService(String fileType);
}

class GenericFileServiceImpl implements GenericFileService {
    private final List<FileService<? extends FileInfo>> candidateFileServices = new ArrayList<>();

    public GenericFileServiceImpl() {
        candidateFileServices.add(new MsdsFileService());
        candidateFileServices.add(new NdgcFileService());
    }

    @Override
    public FileService<? extends FileInfo> getFileService(String fileType) {
        return candidateFileServices.stream()
                .filter(service -> service.support(fileType))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported fileType.");
                });
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends FileInfo, R extends FileService<T>> void saveFileInfo(T fileInfo, R fileService) {
        fileService.saveFileInfo(fileInfo);
    }
}
```